# Validation on 1st page prevents second page to post

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a RadAjaxPanel which contains the following controls:

- RadTabStrip
- RadMultiPage

The RadMultiPage consists of two page views both pages also contains buttons which posts data to the server on server-side.

I also have one RadInputManager which takes care of my validation for both pages.

At the time I was only working with one page view everything worked just fine. However, as soon as my second page view was added I ran into a problem where the second page view won't submit due to required fields not filled out in the first page view, even though all the validations passed on the second form.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set validation Group property of your RequiredFieldValidator for your Pages, like..

```
ValidationGroup="FirstPage"

ValidationGroup="SecondPage"
```

and then in your Submit Button set that validation group to your particular Submit Button

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="FirstPage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="FirstPage" />

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="SecondPage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="SecondPage" />
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion provided me with some clues to the actual problem.